# Silverlight: How to find empty rows in Grid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid, row, silverlight-5.0

I want to find empty rows in `Grid` and remove it from `RowDefinitions`.

I search in the internet but not found any good result about this subject. How can i find empty rows in grid ?

Comment: What is the type of the `ItemsSource` value?

Comment: Grid hasn't `ItemsSource`.

Comment: A question I'd ask is 'why'? If you remove row definitions you'll also have to update the `Grid.Row="X"` of all UI elements below that row. Setting the height of a row to `Auto` essentially hides it if there are no elements declared as being in that row.

Comment: Thank you for reply; I want to remove empty row and Shift  all UI elements up.

Comment: @Mashton : I Add Rows dynamically with height = 40 for example

Comment: Well, if you're dynamically creating the rows and dynamically setting their height I'd suggest making that code smarter so that it doesn't dynamically create rows that will have no content. It seems odd to dynamically create rows and then dynamically remove them. If this because of runtime changes then I'd suggest you use wpf/xaml in the 'normal' way and look into ItemsControls that have an ItemsSource and make use of binding to dynamically change a UI based on databinding.

Comment: OK, I'll test the other ways.